# Playing multiple fractions of HTML5 videos at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, video

I am trying to write a function that will take an id of a div and play a given video from for example 2/10th of the way through to 3/10th of the way through and return an event so I can do something else.

I am not to clever with events as yet, and the video duration is not working out for me, any help appreciated. I have jQuery installed.

Some improvement since last time...
Updated, just need the listener to work next.

```
var finished_event = new Event('finished');

$(document).ready(function(){

    class Player {

        constructor(pos, vid, part, parts){
            this.pos = pos;
            this.vid = vid;
            this.part = part;
            this.parts = parts;
        }

        start(){
            var it = this;

            var html = '<video class="video-fit" controls>';
            html += '<source src="';
            html += it.vid;
            html += '" type="video/mp4">';
            html += '</video>';
            $(it.pos).html(html);

            var video = $(it.pos + ' video')[0];

            video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(){

              var dur = video.duration;
              var fra = dur / it.parts;
              var beg = it.part * fra;
              var end = it.part * (fra + 1);
              video.currentTime = beg;
              video.play();

              video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {

                 if (video.currentTime >= end) {
                   video.pause();
                   this.dispatchEvent(finished_event);
                 }

              }, false);

            }, false);

            return it;
        }
    }

  $('body').click(function(){
    let player_1 = new Player('#pos-1', 'videos/576p.mp4', 5, 10);
    player_1.start();
    let player_2 = new Player('#pos-2', 'videos/576p.mp4', 5, 10);
    player_2.start();
    let player_3 = new Player('#pos-3', 'videos/576p.mp4', 5, 10);
    player_3.start();
    let player_4 = new Player('#pos-4', 'videos/576p.mp4', 5, 10);
    player_4.start();

    //.addEventListener('finished', function(){ console.log('Finished'); }, false)

  });

});
```

Comment: if i understant, you want to play a part of video wich starts at middle and finish at end (5/10 and 10/10) for example?

Comment: I'm playing a nth of the video that is n units long. I have got that working but I am a bit confused over the listener and setting it up for finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timeupdate` event fires a lot, so it could fire multiple times within the `this.currentTime >= end` check.

Not changing your code too much, you would want to set a playing state/var and on `canplay` event change timestamp and then play, this would, in turn, trigger a `seeked` event which then you can set the video as playing, then on `timeupdate`, check your timing plus is the video playing.. and for the last video you would need to check `ended` event as it won't enter into your check `this.currentTime >= end` as end is +1 second.

Then to separate the event functions from the Player class, id would use an array and watch it for changes, then by pushing a function to the array/stack you can then do a check within the function each time its invoked if the stack matches the video length, suppose you could do it other ways.

```js
(function () {
  let video =
    'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/twitter_cat.mp4';

  let videos = [
    { id: '#pos-1', video, part: 1, parts: 10 },
    { id: '#pos-2', video, part: 2, parts: 10 },
    { id: '#pos-3', video, part: 3, parts: 10 },
    { id: '#pos-4', video, part: 4, parts: 10 },
  ];

  const playqueue = [];
  Object.defineProperty(playqueue, 'push', {
    value: function (...args) {
      var arr = Array.prototype.push.apply(this, args)
      if (typeof args[0] === 'function') args[0]();
      return arr;
    }
  });

  function finished_event() {
    if (playqueue.length === videos.length) {
      console.log('Do something, all videos have stopped playing');
    }
  }

  function video_finished_event(player) {
    console.log(
      'Do something, ' + JSON.stringify(player) + ' has stopped playing'
    );

    playqueue.push(finished_event);
  }

  class Player {
    constructor(pos, vid, part, parts) {
      this.pos = pos;
      this.vid = vid;
      this.part = part;
      this.parts = parts;
    }

    start() {
      var it = this;

      var html = '<video class="video-fit" data-vid="' + it.pos + '" controls>';
      html += '<source src="';
      html += it.vid;
      html += '" type="video/mp4">';
      html += '</video>';
      $(it.pos).html(html);

      var video = $('[data-vid="' + it.pos + '"]')[0];

      video.addEventListener(
        'loadeddata',
        function () {
          var fra = video.duration / it.parts;
          var beg = it.part * fra;
          var end = it.part * (fra + 1);

          video.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
            if (!this.playing) {
              this.currentTime = beg;
              this.play();
            }
          });

          video.addEventListener('seeked', function () {
            this.playing = true;
          });

          video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
            if (this.playing && this.currentTime >= end) {
              this.pause();
              this.playing = false;
              video_finished_event(it);
            }
          });

          video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            if (this.playing) {
              this.pause();
              this.playing = false;
              video_finished_event(it);
            }
          })
        },
        false
      );

      return it;
    }
  }

  videos.forEach(video => {
    video.player = new Player(video.id, video.video, video.part, video.parts);
    video.player.start();
  });
})();
```

```css
.videos div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(25vw - 15px);
  height: 100%;
}

.videos div video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videos">
  <div id="pos-1"></div>
  <div id="pos-2"></div>
  <div id="pos-3"></div>
  <div id="pos-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it does the job outlined, but not sure it helps my final goal. I was trying to sequentialy play multiple videos in multiple positions from multiple queues. I should have said that at the beginning, but I will still give credit were credit is due.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put an unique id on video, here i choose vpos-1/2/3/4/...
and i display video from beg to end:

```
var html = '<video ' + 'id="v' + it.pos + '" class="video-fit">';
            html += '<source src="';
            html += it.vid;
            html += '" type="video/mp4">';
            html += '</video>';
            $(it.pos).html(html);

var video = document.getElementById('v' + it.pos);

$(video).bind('timeupdate', function() {
    if(video.currentTime > end){
       video.pause();
    }
});

$(video).on('play', function() {
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    //calcul the value of beg
    video.currentTime = beg;
    video.play();//suppress if you have autoplay
});

$(video).bind('ended', function() {
    // nothing yet      
});
```

if you want to autoplay and/or display controls i suggest you to add

```
controls="controls" autoplay
```

to tag `video`

if you want to remove video: just do `src=''`

It stops the video and it saves the memory